# How do I make this so that way whenever the user says no it will stop or terminate the program? Currently, it's not doing that

Tags: while-loop

```
def Main():
    global more
    InitializeReport()
    TeamCode()
    more = input("Do you have more to enter?")

    while (more != "N" or "No" or "n" or "no"):
        ProcPlyr()
        more = input("Do you have more to enter?")
    CalcAvg()
    DisplaySummary()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (more == "N" or more == "No" or more == "n" or more =="no"):
exit()
```